# Enumerate method arguments

Tags: objective-c

Is there any way to iterate over method arguments of objective-c methods? I need to do a lot of error checking in a lot of methods and would like to automate that instead of checking each value that comes in individually.

I know this can be done for methods with a variable number of arguments. But I am particularly looking for a way to do this with methods that take a fixed number of arguments.

```
- (void)myMethodWithArg1:(NSString *)arg1 arg2:(NSNumber *)arg3 NSError:(NSError **)err {

    // Get all arguments as array
    NSArray *args; // ???

    for (id arg in args) {
        // Do stuff with args ....
    }
}
```

Comment: What sort of error checking are you doing?  Won't each parameter of each method have different requirements, making automated testing difficult?

Comment: The details of error checking are not important for now. I'm just looking for a way to get the arguments as a collection.

Comment: Instead of writing your app?

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following.

```
- (void)myMethodWithArg1:(NSString *)arg1 arg2:(NSNumber *)arg3 NSError:(NSError **)err 
{
    NSArray *args = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:arg1, arg2, err, nil];

    for(id arg in args) {

        if(arg) {
            // Your code that you want to do with each arg here.
        }
    }    

}
```

There is nothing special going on here all that is happening is that your initializing an `NSArray` with objects the objects being your arguments, then once in the `for loop` you are just checking that `arg` is something and not just `nil` or `null`. When in that `for loop` its all you again to do what ever you want with that argument and to determine what it is.

If this isn't what you are looking for please just comment and I will amend to help best possible.

Comment: This will not work in case arg1 is nil. Im looking for functionality similar to va_start & va_list for variable argument lists in cocoa. I do not want to create the array myself.

Comment: @nhyolo let me have a play around and I will get back to you and edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Passing a variable number of arguments to a method is a convenient way to handle a list of variables that are in scope at compile time.

Objective-C handles variable arguments in the same way that Standard C does. Normally, you will encounter variable argument lists in one of two forms: "Format strings" or "Nil terminated lists".

**va_list in C**

A number of classes in Cocoa have methods that take variable numbers of arguments. In most cases, these classes will also have an equivalent method that takes a va_list.

We can see an example of these `va_list` equivalents by looking at NSString. NSString declares the class method `stringWithFormat:...` (which takes a variable number of arguments) and NSString also declares the instance method `initWithFormat:arguments:` (where the arguments parameter is a `va_list`) which handles the equivalent behavior of `stringWithFormat:....`

These `va_list` methods are used in the situation where your class defines a method with a variable argument list and you need to pass those variable arguments into the Cocoa method.

```
- (void)logMessage:(NSString *)format, ... {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    NSLogv(format, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

I'm not aware of a way to analyse the method parameters, if you specify them in a single way.